# Excel VBA how to express Do loop until activecell.value = value in specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I try

```
Do
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+0.01"
Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = "$C$1"
```

But it's not working

Pls. help

i try to add + 0.01 from first value (1) until equal last value (1.9)

Here is my all code

```
[Sub ExtractRC()


  Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).Select
  Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Select
  Selection.Copy
  Range("C1").Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Range("k2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("A2").Value

Do
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R\[-1\]C+0.01"
Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = "$C$1"

End Sub][1]
```

P.S. Value in Column A can change

Comment: You are changing the value of the `ActiveCell` **before** you are actually checking it's value (you probably meant to use a `Do While` loop). Note, this is quite poor programming alltogether. You should avoid `Range.Select`, and if you want to add formulas to a `Range` object, there are ways to do so in a single go.

Comment: As @JvdV said - there will be a way to do it in a single go.  I don't know what range of cells you're trying to fill - it can't be row 1 as you're looking at the previous row.  This code would add that formula to A2:A5 in one go: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A5").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+0.01"`

Comment: I add some details . Hope it make more clear for my question.